# Extract from file words with specific len

Tags: python, file, list-comprehension

I have a file that contains sentences. I want to extract those sentences to a list and remove the words with length <=3

This is what I have by now:

```
with open("./data/pos/train-pos.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    train_pos = [line.strip().lower() for line in f]
    newDoc = [word for word in train_pos if len(word) >= 3]
    print(newDoc)
```

> train-pos = ['i like apples', 'apples are my favorite fruits']

And I want to obtain: `['like apples', 'apples favorite fruits']`, but I obtain the same list. Which is the problem? I want to do this in a very optimal way because `train-pos.txt` contains thousands of sentences so if your solution is different than my wrong solution, there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> newDoc = [' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if len(word) >= 3) for sentence in train_pos]
>>> newDoc
['like apples', 'apples are favorite fruits']
```